# Include R output as pdf in Texmaker

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texmaker, plot, r

I just switched from [texshop](/questions/tagged/texshop) to [texmaker](/questions/tagged/texmaker) on `Mac OS X`. However, now the plots I want to insert from `R` as pdf in the document are missing the fonts in the    `pdflatex` output. It used to work fine with Texshop, but I need Texmaker .Jpeg format has low quality. What is the problem?

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathstyle}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[sort,comma,numbers,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{ael}
\caption{\label{fig:your-figure}Simulated distribution of $\alpha$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I attach an image that shows the plot without fonts.[image: Bildschirmfoto 2014-02-20 um 11.33.11]

This it what it looks like in the pdf.

[image]

Comment: So, you included `ael.pdf` which is *immutable* file, what is the matter?

Comment: It is immutable in Texshop, but as it seems not in Texmaker.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean the PDF you included appears different in the document?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. All the fonts dissappear from the plot, I have attached the image above.

Comment: That's because the image ae1.pdf is not totally and clearly defined : the font used for the text is not embed or clearly defined and the poppler library used by the internal pdf viewer of texmaker was not able to find the correct font or make a valid substitution. You can recreate the ae1.pdf image in a more robust way (warning : with ps2pdf, you must be sure that the font is correctly defined). You can aso use the standard macosx pdf viewer with texmaker : just check the "external viewer" option.

Comment: If you work regularly with R and TeX consider `knitr`: http://yihui.name/knitr/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mainly a viewer issue.